# async/await functions have strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a nodejs / javascript app and have some issues with async / await. I have checked many of the suggestions given here, but cannot find one that fits my issue. If there is one out there I apologise in advance.

I have a function that gets information from a websocket stream. This information is buffered, awaiting further processing.

The function that processes the information from the stream (updateOrderBook) is called every second, using a setTimeout.

In order to be able to process the stream data, an order book must exist. If it doesn't one shall be created. That function (createOrderBook) needs to get data from a REST API and here is where I have the problems.

In updateOrderBook I'm awaiting the createOrderBook function.
createOrderBook in its turn awaits axios from returning the REST API data. But whilst awaiting this API data it seems that control is returned back to updateOrderBook.

So what am I overlooking here? and more importantly how can I fix it?

```
const updateOrderBook = () => {
  // select the coin at hand
  dataBuffer.forEach(async (data, index) => {
    dataBuffer.splice(index, 1);
    let symbol = data.s.toLowerCase();

    if (orderBook.filter(orders => orders.coin === symbol).length === 0) {
      await createOrderBook(symbol);
      console.log(`${symbol}: Orderbook created`);
    }

    if (typeof lastUpdateId[symbol] == "undefined") {
      console.log(
        symbol,
        "UNDEFINED",
        orderBook.filter(orders => orders.coin === symbol).length === 0
      );
    }
    ...
  setTimeout(() => updateOrderBook(), 1000);
};
```

```
const createOrderBook = async (symbol) => {
  console.log(symbol, "ENTERED COB");
  orderBook.push({ coin: symbol, bids: [], asks: [] });
  firstEvent[symbol] = true;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://www.binance.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=${symbol.toUpperCase()}&limit=1000`
    );
    console.log(symbol, "BEFORE ENTERING HIO");
    handleInitialOrderBook(response, symbol.toLowerCase());
    console.log(symbol, "COB");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(symbol, error);
  }
};
```

Expected log:

```
xrpusdt BEFORE ENTERING HIO
xrpusdt HIO
xrpusdt COB
xrpusdt: Orderbook created
```

Actual log:

```
xrpusdt ENTERED COB
xrpusdt UNDEFINED false
xrpusdt BEFORE ENTERING HIO
xrpusdt HIO
xrpusdt COB
xrpusdt: Orderbook created
```

As you can see the UNDEFINED log which I expect to happen, if at all, after createOrderBook finishes came before createOrderBook completely finished

Comment: It appears that the dataBuffer contains some data that does not pass the filter conditional after the first iteration. So the async `if` runs as expected and then the sync `if` runs and to create the race condition you see.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - I don't get it yet, can you explain more indepth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies within:

```
dataBuffer.forEach(async (data, index) => {
  // ...
});
```

Although the callback function is an async function. `forEach` doesn't check the return value of this callback and does not await the returned promise before calling the next iteration.

Currently the first element in the buffer is waiting for `createOrderBook` to finish, while the second element skips the if-block:

```
if (orderBook.filter(orders => orders.coin === symbol).length === 0)
```

This is because `createOrderBook` calls `orderBook.push(...)` before awaiting, thus the element is already pushed and the JavaScript engine will move on the the next element in `forEach` as soon as it needs to `await` within `createOrderBook`.

So how do you solve this? The easiest way would be to not use a `forEach` call, but instead use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Because you are not creating new callback functions the main function will await the promise and only move on once it is resolved.

```
for (const [index, data] of dataBuffer.entries()) {
  // ...
}
```

For this to work you do have to change `updateOrderBook` into an async function. The code block above assumes that `dataBuffer` is an array, if it is another object you might have to check the documentation on how to get an iterator with both the index and element.

> **Note:** By using `dataBuffer.splice(index, 1)` within the loop you get some strange behaviour. On the first element `index` is `0` and the first element is removed. This will shift the whole array. Normally you don't want to mutate an array while you are iterating over it. This can be solved in one of two ways:
>
> 1. Use `for (const data of dataBuffer)` instead and splice of all elements after you are done iterating. `dataBuffer.slice(0)` (clears the array).
> 2. Use a while-loop instead.
>
>    ```
>    while (dataBuffer.length > 0) {
>      const data = dataBuffer.shift();
>      // ...
>    }
>    ```

```js
const letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

for (const [index, letter] of letters.entries()) {
  console.log(index, letter);
  letters.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(letters);
```

---

```
const updateOrderBook = async () => {
  // select the coin at hand
  while (dataBuffer.length > 0) {
    const data = dataBuffer.shift();
    let symbol = data.s.toLowerCase();

    if (orderBook.filter(orders => orders.coin === symbol).length === 0) {
      await createOrderBook(symbol);
      console.log(`${symbol}: Orderbook created`);
    }

    if (typeof lastUpdateId[symbol] == "undefined") {
      console.log(
        symbol,
        "UNDEFINED",
        orderBook.filter(orders => orders.coin === symbol).length === 0
      );
    }
  }

  // ...
  setTimeout(() => updateOrderBook(), 1000);
};
```

Comment: @MPL Just to make sure I've added a code block of how the result should look. Could you cross-reference this with the changes you made? The code above should never log `"UNDEFINED"` before `"Orderbook created"`. If it is still doing that there might be something else wrong.

Comment: I used a plane old while loop -- which worked. Will try your solution as well. 2 extra questions, is it ok to splice the dataBuffer and can I use a continue to jump to the next itteration?

Comment: @MPL I've updated the answer with an important note. Mutating the array (removing elments) while iterating it may result in strange behaviour because all other elements start to shift.

Comment: This is the solution I came up with as well. I just do dataBuffer.shift()
And at the end within the loop a delay of 0 ms, to make sure it will not run forever. the stream might be adding to the buffer async.

Comment: @MPL `shift` is probably better. I used `splice` because you where already using it, I'll update my answer to use `shift` as well if you don't mind.